# Expectation of exponential of an additive functional of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I have a question about an additive functional of Brownian motion.

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $b:\mathbb{R}^{d}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function and $(X_{t})_{t \in [0,\infty[}$ be a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion.

I want to get an upper estimate of the following integral
\begin{align*}
E \left[ \exp \left(\int_{0}^{t}b(X_{s})^{2}ds \right) \right].
\end{align*}

For example if $b$ is bounded,
\begin{align*}
E \left[ \exp \left(\int_{0}^{t}b(X_{s})^{2}ds \right) \right] &\leq \exp\left( M^{2}t\right) \\
& \left(\to 0 \quad \mbox{as} \quad t \to0 \right)
\end{align*}
where $M=\mbox{esssup}|b|$.

**My question**

For an **unbounded or integrable** $b$ , can we get an upper estimate or a small time asymptotic of $E \left[ \exp \left(\int_{0}^{t}b(X_{s})^{2}ds \right) \right]$ ?

Thank you for your consideration.